# compile errors using signal.h in Linux

Tags: c, linux, signals, system-calls, signal-handling

I'm writing a shell program that must handle signals. My relevant signal handling related code is as follows:

```
#include <signal.h>
...
#include <sys/types.h>
...
void installSigactions( int, struct sigaction* );

void handler_function( int signal_id );
...
/*define signal table*/
struct sigaction signal_action;

/*insert handler function*/
signal_action.sa_handler = handler_function;

/*init the flags field*/
 signal_action.sa_flags = 0;

/*are no masked interrupts*/
sigemptyset( &signal_action.sa_mask );

/*install the signal_actions*/
sigaction( SIGINT, &signal_action, NULL );
```

Compiling gives me the following warnings and errors:

```
gcc -Wall -ggdb -ansi -static -pedantic -o os1shell2 os1shell2.c
os1shell2.c:35: warning: 'struct sigaction' declared inside parameter list
os1shell2.c:35: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, 
which is probably not what you want
os1shell2.c: In function 'main':
os1shell2.c:66: error: storage size of 'signal_action' isn't known
os1shell2.c:75: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sigemptyset'
os1shell2.c:78: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sigaction'
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting these warnings and errors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will work if you remove `-ansi` from your compile line. I suspect the problem is that the posix parts of the signal library aren't included when you specify `-ansi`.

If you really don't want to disable -ansi, you can also add `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to the compiler options.

[Here is a short discussion of ANSI and the gcc feature test macros](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_27.html).

Comment: removing `-ansi` leaves me with:
`/tmp/ccl4HmT7.o: In function main':`
`/home/stu1/s11/gaw9451/Courses/OS_3/os1shell2.c:68: undefined`
`reference to handler_function'`
`collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Adding the `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE` does the same. Any ideas on this??

Comment: Do you have `handler_function` defined anywhere? It's declared in your question, but there's no code for it. I had to add `void handler_function( int signal_id ) {}`, and then your code compiled fine.